# What should the format of a map with list look like in SpEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I'm trying to read a map of lists from `application.properties` in a spring batch application

```java
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Map<String, List<String>> mapOfLists = (Map<String, List<String>>) parser.parseExpression("{'KEY1':{'value1','value2'},'KEY2':{'value3','value4'},'KEY3': {'value5'}}").getValue();
```

The above works fine but when I put the same value in `application.properties` as `map-of-lists={'KEY1':{'value1','value2'},'KEY2':{'value3','value4'},'KEY3': {'value5'}}`  and try to read the key using `@Value("#{${map-of-lists}}") final Map<String, List<String>> mapOfLists` spring isn't happy and errors out saying it cant find the value.

The same works if I update the key and `@Value` type to `Map<String, String>`

I did not read into how spring is parsing the value but is there a way to do this?

Also, is `@Value` a good way to read from `application.properties` for a map of lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of looking and debugging the below works. I had to add escape character for `,` and that did the job

```json
map-of-lists={KEY1:{value1\,value2}\,KEY2:{value3\,value4}\,KEY3:{value5}}
```

this can later be read as

```java
@Value("#{${map-of-lists}}") final Map<String, List<String>> mapOfLists
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Value("#{${map-of-lists}}")
private Map<String, List<String>> mapOfLists;
```

**application.properties**

```
map-of-lists={'KEY1':{'value1','value2'}, 'KEY2':{'value1','value2'}}
```

In the case of application.yml it should be:

```
map-of-lists: "{'KEY1':{'value1','value2'}, 'KEY2':{'value1','value2'}}"
```

Comment: Can you verify if " is needed for `map-of-lists`? I tried with " enclosed and error *java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Map': no matching editors or conversion strategy found* occur. And it run successfully without " enclosed.

Comment: You are right. `"` is needed in case `application.yml` is used. Answer updated.

Comment: How is this any different than what I already have?

Comment: @TarunKolla what's the exception you get?

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'key' in value "#{${key}}"`

Would you like the full stack trace? I can update the question with it

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if `@Value` annotation supports it. I see a map of map in the spring docs example but not a map of list. Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-inline-lists